# Html page don't detect angularjs element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i want to a print message in html page ,in which message is written in angularjs linked with the html file.

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="../scripts/angular.js"></script>

        <script src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>

    </body>
    </html>
```

script.js

```
var MainController = function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "hellow";
};
```

Anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: is your controller loaded properly??

Comment: check debug console in your browser for javascript errors etc..

Comment: btw you don't need to load both angular.js & angular.min.js, only 1 is required. It's the same code but 2nd one is minified.

Comment: see this:   https://jsfiddle.net/zvhqvzjt/10/

Comment: You directive `ngApp` has no value. your controller is messed up. here's a quick [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bv4OdtAhGAlC0k71tGgl?p=preview) based on your snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a very good and simple example to understand this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.firstName = "John";
$scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You'll need to create the app first
angular.module('myApp', []);

// and then define your controller 
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainController', function MainController() {

});

// in your html, you need to add your root module to ng-app
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Define angular.module and assign it to ng-app.

Have a [look](http://code-maven.com/hello-world-with-angular-controller) at hello world in angularJs

Answer (score 0):

A controller should belong to some module. Make the following corrections and you will be fine:

1. Add the following line at the top of `script.js`:

   angular.module('myModule').controller('MainController', MainController);
2. Tell html which module to use:

   <html ng-app='myModule'>

Answer (score 0):

Issue is before binding the controller with html, you will have to make angular module first. And that controller will be the part of that module only.
You have to bind angular module with html by ng-app then you have to bind controller by ng-controller directive.

### Example:

```
JavaScript
---------
<script src="../scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var MainController = function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "hellow";
    };

    angular.module('mainModule', [])
    .controller('mainCntrl', MainController)
</script>

Html
----
<body ng-app="mainModule">
 <div ng-controller="mainCntrl">
    {{message}}
 </div>
</body>
```